# Use QEMU to build docker image for AM5728 ARM based processor

Tags: ubuntu, build, arm, qemu, texas-instruments

My software application runs inside a Ubuntu 16.04 docker image that I build myself. Now I want to switch to using an ARM based computer - TI Sitara AM5728. Is it possible to use QEMU to build an ARM-based docker image for AM5728 from my x86 laptop?